# Handling roles by dividing users in multiple tables/models

Tags: orm, relational-database

My application has several kinds of users with different sets of properties, for example: customers and employees. One user may be belong to more than one of these roles.
So I decided to have this (simplified example) structure of my database:

```
users (contains the fields applicable to all different kinds of users)
  id
  username
  email

customers (contains fields applicable to customer role)
  id
  user_id
  shipping_address

employees (contains fields applicable to employee role)
  id
  user_id
  salary
```

Question 1: Is this a good way of handling user roles with many different properties?
In reality I have six roles with sets of 7-20 properties. Some of the roles are not even conventionar roles, but bore like extra properties. If a user decides to login with a Facebook acoount, then the Facebook_account table is applicable.

Question 2: When using an ORM, in my case Eloquent, would it make sense to have the role model (customers) extend the user model?
When I fetch a customer object I really want all user och customer properties together, without having to merge them manually.